# Message receiving with JMSCorrelationID not working after JMS/ MQ Upgrade upper- & lower- case issue

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

**Context**

We have a very specific IBM MQ Series based communication between a Java/ Spring application and a Mainframe application. I abstract all of those information (like how you loose the MQMD in the IMS Bridge) as its a more JMS/ MQ related question.

When using JMS specification 1.x and IBM MQ 7.5x we could perfectly correlate 
`JMSCorrelationID`s that as String looked like `ID:F5F5F0F1F5F1404040404040404040404040404040404040` which after the `ID:` part are a IBM 500 (ebcdic) encoded HEX String.

**The Upgrade**

On the Java's system side we upgraded:

- JMS Specification 1.x to 2.0
- IBM MQ 7.5.x drivers to 9.0.2.0
- New Queue Manager to support IBM MQ 9.0.2.0

while on the mainframe side we didnt change anything. Now since this upgrade the messages dont get received as long as the String's representation is in upper case.

**Summary of the issue**

We have the exact same issue as described in [IT19225: MQ-JMS QUEUEBROWSER USING A SELECTOR WITH AN UPPERCASE JMSCORRELATIONID DOES NOT FIND MESSAGES](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IT19225) with the only problem that we are on IBM MQ 9.0.2.0 where the above issue was fixed.

** A Example** 
So when trying to receive a `JMSCorrelationID` that looks like `ID:F5F5F0F1F5F1404040404040404040404040404040404040` (it actually doesn't matter if its a lower- or upper- case representation) the following happens:

Messages with a `MQ CorrelId` as String-Representation with Uppercase won't get picked up, while when the string representation is in lowercase (`ID:f5f5f0f1f5f1404040404040404040404040404040404040"` are received.

*What i tried:*

- change the `JMSCorrelationID` to lowercase when receiving
- change the `JMSCorrelationID` to uppercase when receiving
- Input Messages manually to the queue with the result that

`MQ CorrelId` in lowercase gets received, while `MQ CorrelId` in uppercase does not get received no matter.

- currently trying to bypass the entire "JMS/ MQ Driver" Magic and somehow inject the correlation id as the byte array it is on the MQ side...

Any help would be appreciated as i am stunned that i cant find such an issue with google at all (except the bug that was fixed...)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If the APAR description fits the issue you are having you need to upgrade to MQ v9.0.3 CD, for more details see my longer update below.

---

A few notes about IBM MQ version numbers:

At MQ v9.0 and later IBM split the releases into two streams.  Long Term Support (LTS) and Continuous Delivery (CD).  LTS releases will have version where the forth number changes, for example 9.0.0.2 where CD releases will have a version where the third number changes, for example 9.0.2.

IBM will provide defect support for LTS releases for the life of the major release of MQ (9.0 for example), for v9.0 CD IBM originally [stated](https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS216-153) defect fixes and security updates are only available for the two, most current CD updates.  The final 9.0 CD release is 9.0.5, so they would have only supported 9.0.4 and 9.0.5.  But with the release of 9.1 CD they updated this support statement ([retroactively for 9.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pla.doc/q004715_.html) to state "Defect support for a CD release is available for 12 months from the availability of the release, or while it remains one of the two most recent CD releases, whichever is longer.".  9.0.2 was released on March 17th 2017 and is not one of the two must recent CD releases would no longer qualify for defect support from IBM.  9.0.3 was released in May 30 2017 so is in the same boat, so at this point under either the original support statement or the new support statement the only CD releases that will be supported by IBM through the end of support of v9.0 will be 9.0.4 and 9.0.5 the last two releases of v9.0 CD.

---

In your question you say you are using v9.0.2 (CD) not 9.0.0.2 (LTS).  The APAR you mention states it was fixed in 9.0.0.2 LTS.  Although the APAR page does not mention it being fixed at a CD release, this would be strange since 9.0.0.2 was releases October 5 2017, I noted that 9.0.4 CD was released November 6 2017 and 9.0.5 CD was released March 16 2018.  I have in the past noted that IBM is frequently not accurate in planned release date listed on each published APAR and also when comparing to the fixlist for each release.  I check the 9.0 CD [fixlist](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048961) page and can see it states that APAR IT19225 was fixed in 9.0.3 CD.

Since this is a client side issue there is no reason that could not update to the latest 9.0.5 jar files to get this fix, although you should inform your MQ support team that they are using a out of support version on the queue manager.  You can download the Java-ALL self extracting jar file from the MQ v9.0 client download page: [MQC9: IBM MQ V9 Clients](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176).  Note they do not even list the 9.0.3 and earlier for download since they are no longer supported.

---

My personal recommendation:

If you are going to stay with v9.0 you would be better off going with the 9.0 LTS release at least on the client side (currently at 9.0.0.4 also available at the client download link above).

My reasons:

- The main reason to go with the CD release stream is to take advantage of new functionality that IBM adds in those releases.
- The CD releases are every few months, but eventually after around 2 years IBM rolls all the new CD features into a new LTS release.  This happened on July 23 2018 when v9.1 was released, there will be no more v9.0 CD releases as the those will be done against the latest version 9.1, ex 9.1.1 will come out with new features at some point.
- 9.0.5 was the last v9.0 CD release.
- v9.0 was released by IBM June 2 2016 and IBM states at least 5 years before end of support is announced, but they usually go a little over this.  v8.0 was released June 13 2014 and EOS is April 30 2020.  v7.1/v7.5/v8.0 all had April 30th EOS dates, so my guess following the recent pattern is that 9.0 will go out of support on April 30 2022.
- I do not remember noting any major enhancements to the IBM MQ Classes for JMS being announced in any 9.0 CD releases, so you would not loose any functionality moving to the LTS release (you can go though the list in the Knowledge Center to double check: [What's new and changed in Version 9.0.x Continuous Delivery](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q128110_.html)
- You would gain better support as 9.0 LTS releases with fixes to identified defects (APARS) will continue to be released until it is EOS.
- If you went with 9.0.5, if you find any other defect you would need to go to IBM for a IFIX to apply to 9.0.5, this is also only available to companies with a support contract with IBM (not sure of your situation but I see some cases where someone supports a client app that connects to a queue manager at another company so they do not actually have the support relationship with IBM).
- On the queue manager side the same thing could be recommended assuming you are not using any of the new queue manager features that were added to 9.0.1 or 9.0.2.